# Rails with unicorn showing 2 different version of same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I have a rails 4.1 app that is using nginx and unicorn.

Lets say I make a change to html of a page and push it live. If I navigate to that page or refresh it, I randomly get either the old page or the new updates.

This happens with assets as well. For example refreshing a page will get me either the old version of my css file or the newest version. Obviously this causes a ton of issues.

I am using the default asset pipeline.

I've tried running `rake:tmp:clear`. I've tried using `Rails.tmp.clear` from Rails production console. Neither have worked.

This is a really strange issue that I can't seem to get my head around.

Comment: How do you push your changes? What command to you use to restart unicorn after updating the application?

Comment: I'm just pulling my changes from github currently. The command I run to restart unicorn is `sudo service unicorn_appname restart` . I've tried stopping unicorn and restarting it manually and that does not fix the issue either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the pid of your unicorn with `ps au | grep unicorn`, it may freeze after update.
If afrer `kill -USR2 unicorn` pid is the same you should restart unicorn hard with `kill -9 unicorn` and run it back or run deploy script again.

Comment: This just gives me the pid of the command you told me to run.

Comment: This was close and ultimately led me to figure it out. I ran `ps aux | less` and found a process labeled `unicorn (old)`. Not sure what that it was or why it even existed, but killing the process solved the issue for now.